# how to find upper (top layer )li in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all top **li** from html .I have this mark up

```
<ul class="chapters">
    <li>
        tc_1
    </li>
    <li>
        tc_2<ul>
        <li>tc_1_1</li>
        <li>tc_1_2</li>
        <li>tc_1_3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        tc_3
    </li>
</ul>
```

Expected Answer: `tc_1 ,tc_2,tc_3`

I tried like that actually I inspect and write my code on console .

1. I tried like that `$('li')` and I get `null`
2. Then I put a class attribute "chapters" on ul then try like this
   `$(".chapters")` again and I got `null`.

how to achieve this ?

Comment: try this: $('.chapter li').html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the `childNodes` of the topmost `li` elements and filter their first `textNode`:

```
var textArray = $(".chapters > li").map(function() {
    var nodes = this.childNodes, len = nodes.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        if ( nodes[i].nodeType === 3 && $.trim(nodes[i].nodeValue).length ) {
           return $.trim(nodes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    }
}).get(); 

console.log(textArray.join());
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/f9smLv0v/)

Answer (score 0):

This locates the `ul`, takes its immediate children (each of the `li`s), then removes any subchildren, `.end()`, to return to the `li`s, and `.text()` to get the contents.

```
$("ul").clone().children().children().remove().end().text()
```

This returns

```
"tc_1

            tc_2

            tc_3"
```

because of the line breaks and whitespace in between.

Comment: if I used removed it also remove html from my view http://jsfiddle.net/2zemycu1/2/ ..I just want the contend not to remove from html

Comment: Well, then add a `.clone()`, so it isn't permanently removed.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".chapters li").text()`

should work.

Comment: $(".chapters li") give null to me on console

Comment: Your browser? Are u sure jquery is loaded? Which version r u using?

Comment: Have you properly included a jquery lib (inspect $) ? Do you execute the console command in the correct frame?

Comment: actully sir i am writting my code on console..mean typing f12 key then trying to get li

Comment: So no jquery is loaded.. You should load it within your HTML file

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Add the above line in your HTML file

Comment: if I used removed it also remove html from my view http://jsfiddle.net/2zemycu1/2/ ..I just want the contend not to remove from html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chapters > li').each(function(){
    alert($(this)  .clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text());
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsp82Lqf/1/)

for more explanation you can read http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: if I used removed it also remove html from my view http://jsfiddle.net/2zemycu1/2/ ..I just want the contend not to remove from html